# how to implement another level in table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I had implemented collapsible table view in which first level can be used as sections and the child class can be given as rows count and for another child class how it to be implemented in table view and I am having a expand button if I click on it need to expand and show the third level and the image is shown below libraries can anyone help me how to implement this ?

[image]

and here is my code is shown here which I had already implemented

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return detailsArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return detailsArray[section].childern.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 275, y: 5, width: 30, height: 35))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        headerView.tag = section
        let headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 30)) as UILabel
        headerString.text = detailsArray[section].name
        headerView .addSubview(headerString)
        let btn :UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 35, y: 5, width: 30, height: 35))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        if (detailsArray[section].childern.count != 0){
            btn.setImage(plusImage , for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
        }
        if detailsArray[section].expanded == true {
            btn.setImage(minusImage, for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            btn.setImage(plusImage, for: .normal)
        }
        btn.tag = section
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(btn)
        let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:#selector(sectionHeaderTapped(recognizer:)))
        headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)
        return headerView
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        tableView.isHidden = false
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriescell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCell
        let obj1 = self.detailsArray[indexPath.section].childern[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryLabel?.text = obj1.name
        cell.expandButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.expandButton.setImage(plusImage, for: .normal)
        return cell
    }
    func sectionHeaderTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let newViewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewcontroller, animated: true)
    }
    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let section = sender.tag
        detailsArray[section].expanded = !detailsArray[section].expanded
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0 ..< detailsArray[section].childern.count {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
        }
        if (detailsArray[section].childern.count != 0) {
            if (sender.currentImage == plusImage){
                sender.setImage(minusImage, for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                sender.setImage(plusImage, for: .normal)
            }
        }
        else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tree

Comment: you should take a look [DSNestedAccordion](https://github.com/deepan/DSNestedAccordion)

Comment: it is not possible to do without an third party library ? @Lion

Comment: It is definitely possible. But for that you have to do some hardwork. There are many ways by that you can achieve this. you can refer this libraries code also to know how they are managing this!

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaS Of course it is possible. How do you think that library was created in the first place?

Comment: already I tried by looking into some libraries but got lots of errors unable to implement by using that code @Lion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone UITableView Nested Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342180/iphone-uitableview-nested-sections)